# Solving $\tau^4 +1=u^2 +v^2$ over the integers

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, pell-type-equations, perfect-powers

I'm trying to show, that the solutions $t_i$ from Pell's equation $t^2-2s^2=\pm 1$ are not squares (only for the trivial cases). For the even solutions $t_{2i}$ (solutions for the + sign) this is easy, but for the odd solutions $t_{2i+1}$ (solutions for the - sign) this is a little bit harder.

This question leads to the diophantine equation $\tau^4-2s^2=-1$ and the new question, whether it has nontrivial solutions or not.

I do the following approach. First of all I take the equation
$\tau^4+1=u^2+v^2$ (*),
try to find solutions $(u, v, \tau)$ and set in the end $s=u=v$. With

$\begin{align}
u&=u_2 a^2 +u_1 a+u_0 \\
v&=v_2 a^2 +v_1 a+v_0 \\
\tau&=\tau_1 a+\tau_0
\end{align}$

and comparison of the coefficients one gets

$\begin{align}
u&=2a^2 b^2 (b^4 +1)+4ab^3 +1 \\
v&=a^2 (b^8-1)+2ab(b^4 -1)+b^2 \\
\tau&=a(b^4 +1)+b
\end{align}$

with natural numbers $a$ and $b$.

Now the question: are there any other solutions for (*) and if not, why?
Maybe there is also an easy way showing, that the $t_{2i+1}$ are not squares, then I would prefer this proof.

thank you

Comment: $\tau^4-2s^2=-1$ can be transfomed to $Y^2=2X^4+2$.
$Y^2=2X^4+2$ has only integer solutions $(X,Y)=(\pm1,\pm2)$.
Hence $\tau^4-2s^2=-1$ has only integer solutions $(\tau,s)=(\pm1,\pm1)$.

Comment: thank you, but why are the solutions $(X, Y)=(\pm 1, \pm 2)$ of $Y^2=2X^4 +2$ the only ones?

Comment: in Mordell's book,  page 18, formula (5), he says $x^4 + y^4 = 2 z^2$  with $\gcd(x,y) = 1 $ has integer solutions just $x^2 = y^2 = 1,$  where he is ruling out $(0,0,0)$ Take $y=1$

Comment: seems someone lost count, there are two Theorem 3 in the same chapter. 1 is $x^2 + y^4 = z^2$   ...2 is $x^4 - y^4 = z^2$... (3A page 18) is $x^4 - 6 x^2 y^2 + y^4 = z^2 $...(3B page 21) is There cannot be four squares in arithmetical progression. Not the (integer) square roots, the squares themselves

Comment: thank you for the hint, I think I got it. The best for understandig his arguments is starting with theorem 2 on p. 17.

Comment: I suggest starting on page 16, with the Lemma and Theorem 1. He is settling notation and methodology there; it is after Theorem 1 that he writes a paragraph saying the proof used Fermat's infinite descent, a method he regards as important. I can tell you that many students on MSE have trouble with infinite descent; Mordell is pointing out the difference between assuming you are already in the final, descended, state, and working out the descent before that state is reached. He makes a good point as far as pedagogy

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume your parametrization attempts to cover all solutions up to sign, and up to switching $u$ and $v$, because in your parametrization clearly $u$ and $v$ are both nonnegative, and $u$ is odd. Even then the parametrization is incomplete; there are no natural numbers $a$ and $b$ corresponding to the solution $(\tau,u,v)=(8,31,56)$.

---

Here's the first approach that springs to my mind; it's not necessarily much easier, and the final step is a bit unsatisfying, but it's certainly too much for a comment:

If $\tau$ and $s$ are integers such that $\tau^4-2s^2=-1$ then clearly $\tau$ is odd, and
$$-\tau^4=1-2s^2=(1+s\sqrt{2})(1-s\sqrt{2}).\tag{1}$$
This suggests an argument in $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$, which is a UFD with fundamental unit $1+\sqrt{2}$.  Indeed the two factors on the right hand side are coprime, so both are fourth powers up to units. Then without loss of generality $1+s\sqrt{2}=(1+\sqrt{2})^kr^4$  with $k\in\{0,1,2,3\}$, and comparing norms in $(1)$ shows that $k=1,3$. This yields four quartic Thue equations, two of which have no solutions by reducing mod $4$. The other two have only the trivial solutions $s=\pm1$, found with the aid of a computer package.

**Edited this section to provide excruciating detail and the absolutely minimal amount of theory:**

If $\eta\in\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ divides both factors on the right hand side of $(1)$, then $\eta$ divides their sum, which is
$$(1+s\sqrt{2})+(1-s\sqrt{2})=2.$$
Because $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ is a unique factorization domain, and $2$ factors as $2=\sqrt{2}^2$ where $\sqrt{2}\in\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ is prime, it follows that $\eta=u\sqrt{2}^m$ for some unit $u\in\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]^{\times}$ and some $m\in\{0,1,2\}$. If $m\neq0$ then $\sqrt{2}$ divides both factors, and hence $-\tau^4$ is divisible by $\sqrt{2}^2=2$. But we already noted that $\tau$ is odd; a contradiction. Hence $m=0$ and so $\eta=u$ is a unit in $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$. This shows that the two factors on the right hand side of $(1)$ have no common prime factors. Factoring the two factors as
$$1+s\sqrt{2}=v\cdot p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_k^{e_k}
\qquad\text{ and }\qquad
1-s\sqrt{2}=w\cdot q_1^{f_1}\cdots q_l^{f_l},$$
for units $v,w\in\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]^{\times}$, pairwise coprime primes $p_i,q_j\in\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$, and positive integers $e_i,f_j\in\Bbb{Z}_{>0}$, we see that
$$\tau^4=-(1+st\sqrt{2})(1-s\sqrt{2})=-vw\cdot p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_k^{e_k}q_1^{f_1}\cdots q_l^{f_l}.$$
Because the left hand side is a fourth power, it follows that all $e_i$ and $f_j$ are multiples of $4$. That is to say, we have
$$1+s\sqrt{2}=vr^4\qquad\text{ and }\qquad1-s\sqrt{2}=ws^4,$$
for some units $v,w\in\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]^{\times}$ and $r,s\in\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$. The unit group of $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ is generated by $-1$ and the fundamental unit $1+\sqrt{2}$, so $v=\pm(1+\sqrt{2})^m$ for some integer $m$, and of course $r=x+y\sqrt{2}$ for some integers $x,y\in\Bbb{Z}$, so we find that
$$1+s\sqrt{2}=\pm(1+\sqrt{2})^m(x+y\sqrt{2})^4,$$
for some $m,x,y\in\Bbb{Z}$. Without loss of generality we may assume that $m\in\{0,1,2,3\}$, because
$$(1+\sqrt{2})^m(x+y\sqrt{2})^4=(1+\sqrt{2})^{m-4n}\big((1+\sqrt{2})^n(x+y\sqrt{2})\big)^4,$$
so we can reduce $m$ modulo $4$ and adjust $x$ and $y$ accordingly. Because the map
$$\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]\ \longrightarrow\ \Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]:\ x+y\sqrt{2}\ \longmapsto\ x-y\sqrt{2},$$
is an isomorphism, it follows that
$$1-s\sqrt{2}=\pm(1-\sqrt{2})^m(x-y\sqrt{2})^4,$$
and so
\begin{eqnarray*}
\tau^4&=&-(1+s\sqrt{2})(1-s\sqrt{2})\\
&=&-\big(\pm(1+\sqrt{2})^m(x+y\sqrt{2})^4\big)\big(\pm(1-\sqrt{2})^m(x-y\sqrt{2})^4\big)\\
&=&-\big((1+\sqrt{2})(1-\sqrt{2})\big)^m\big((x+y\sqrt{2})(x-y\sqrt{2})\big)^4\\
&=&-(-1)^m(x^2-2y^2)^4,
\end{eqnarray*}
where of course  $\tau^4$ and $(x^2-2y^2)^4$ are positive, so $m$ is odd, i.e. $m=1$ or $m=3$. This shows that either
$$1+s\sqrt{2}=\pm(1+\sqrt{2})(x+y\sqrt{2})^4
\qquad\text{ or }\qquad
1+s\sqrt{2}=\pm(7+5\sqrt{2})(x+y\sqrt{2})^4,$$
for some integers $x,y\in\Bbb{Z}$. Expanding the fourth power and comparing coefficients shows that
\begn{eqnarray*}
\pm1&=&x^4+8x^3y+12x^2y^2+16xy^3+4y^4,\
\pm1&=&7x^4+40x^3y+84x^2y^2+80xy^3+28y^4,
\end{eqnarray*}
and then reducing mod $4$ shows that we must have the $=$-sign in the first case, and the $-$isgn in the second case.emphasized text These are two [Thue equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue_equation), for which there exist effective methods to determine all integral solutions. With the help of a computer I found that $(x,y)=\pm(1,-1)$ and($(x,y)=(\pm1,0)$ are the only integral solutions, and these all correspond to $s,\tau=\pm1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a question, I didn't understand the coprime-argument, how do you calculate the gcd?

Comment: The sum of the factors is $2$, so their gcd divides $2$.

Comment: Yes, of course, but we are now in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$, so all divisors of 2 are relevant and not only 1 or 2. And this leads us to the original Pell's equation and doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: In $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ the divisors of $2$ are $1$, $\sqrt{2}$ and $2=\sqrt{2}^2$, up to units. So if the two factors are not coprime, then both are divisible by $\sqrt{2}$ and  hence their product is divisible by $2$. But $\tau$ is clearly odd.

Comment: that's right: "up to units". this means for all $t+s\sqrt{2}$ with $t^2 -2s^2=\pm 1$. again, this leads back to the original question and doesn't solve it.

Comment: @buja No, it does not lead back to the original question. It shows that the two factors are coprime. Your original question was about $t^4-2s^2=\pm1$, by the way.

Comment: two numbers a and b are coprime, if $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and this is not the case. and also by the way, if the original question would be $t^2-2s^2=\pm 1$ then your arguments would also lead only to the trivial solutions and not to the solutions of the Pell's equation.

Comment: My argument (in my second comment) shows that $\gcd(a,b)=1$. What part of that is unclear?

Comment: @buja All your claims are both false and irrelevant. I'm not sure how to respond other that *"No."*. If there is any part of my argument is unclear then I'll gladly try to clarify it, but simply stating outright that my result is false (even though it is true) is extremely unconstructive.

Comment: the whole time I try to explain whats wrong with your arguments. first of all you have right that 1, $\sqrt{2}$ and 2 (up to units) are divisors of 2 and 2 vanishes because the product of the two numbers is odd. but then 1 and $\sqrt{2}$ (up to units) still remains and this means $\gcd(a, b)\neq 1$. I also try to show you, that your arguments are going wrong with Pell's equation. Take $-t^2 =1-2s^2$ and calculate in your way the solutions (s, t). Without the units $t\pm s\sqrt{2}$ you only get the trivial solutions because the solutions are in all the other units. I do not only say "no".

Comment: To your first point: As I mentioned in my second comment, if $\sqrt{2}$ divides the gcd then $\sqrt{2}\cdot\sqrt{2}=2$ divides the product. But the product is $-\tau^4$ which is odd. So $\sqrt{2}$ does not divide the gcd, so the gcd is a unit, i.e. the two factors are coprime.

Comment: To your point about the units; I have no idea how any of that relates to my argument. Have you read beyond the point where I show that the factors are coprime?

Comment: ok, to the point with the units: $1+\sqrt{2}$ is for instance such an unit and a divisor of 2 and if I square it I get $3+2\sqrt{2}$ which you can't delete with the "odd"-argument of the product. and of course, I read all of your answer and I hoped that would be true, really.

Comment: I still have no idea how any of this relates to my argument. I don't 'delete' any units; the conclusion of the factors being coprime is that
$$1+s\sqrt{2}=uz^4,$$
for some unit $u\in\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]^{\times}$ and some $z\in\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$. Are you familiar with unique factorization domains (UFDs)? See for example [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain) for the definition and basic facts.

Comment: Note that two factors are coprime if they have no common *prime* factors; units are irrelevant. Of course the gcd is only defined up to units to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

First, we can find not-all-solutions but  gain insights by re-arranging terms.
$$\tau^4 +1=u^2 +v^2\quad \implies  
\tau^4-u^2 =v^2-1\quad \text{or}\quad  \tau^4 -v^2=u^2-1$$

$$\implies (\tau^2)^2-u^2 =v^2-1\quad \text{or}\quad (\tau^2)^2 -v^2=u^2-1\\
\implies u=v=\pm\sqrt{\tau} \quad\lor\quad \tau=u=v=\pm1$$

but this is only a tiny subset of solutions and empirical data might offer more insights. Let

$$\tau = \sqrt[4]{u^2 +v^2-1}$$

$$\big\{(0,1,0)\big\} \\ 
\big\{(0,0,1), \space  (1,1,1), \space (2,4,1), \space (3,9,1), \space (4,16,1), \space (5,25,1), \space (6,36,1),\space  \cdots\big\}\\ 
\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\big\{(2,1,4),\space (3,1,9),\space (4,1,16),\space (5,1,25),\space  (6,1,36)\quad \cdots\big\} $$

$$\big\{(8,56,31), \space (8,31,56)\big\}\quad 
\big\{(9,71,39),\space (9,39,71)\big\} \quad 
 \big\{(14,191,44), \space (18,321,44)\big\}\quad
 \big\{(10,76,65), \space (10,65,76)\big\} \quad\cdots $$

We see a pattern in many/most solutions but $u,v$ values of $31, 39, 44, 56, 65,71,76,\cdots $ make "patterns" more elusive, except that $u,v$ are interchangeable in many cases. These numbers were derive from tests of $u \le 3000\land v\le 100$. Beyond that, we do have the complimentary cases of
$(14,44,191), \space (18,44,321).$ What remains is the puzzle of the non-squares.